# how to add an element of array to another object and count number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object

Firstly, I have an array with object element like below:

```
$scope.selectedIngredient = [object1, object2, object3, object1, object2];
```

secondly , I have a new object :

```
$scope.selectedIngredientResults = {};
```

Now I wanna achieve one function in javascript like this:

count each object element of array and put them into a new object and store each

count

```
$scope.selectedIngredientResults = [

    {"object" : object1, "count" : 2},
    {"object" : object2, "count" : 2},
    {"object" : object3, "count" : 1}

];
```

[image: here is array with object elements]

[![here is new object result, this is what I want,

I was trying using

```
$scope.addIngredient = function(selectedElement) {

console.log('selectedElement', selectedElement);
$scope.selectedIngredient.push(selectedElement);
console.log('$scope.selectedIngredient' , $scope.selectedIngredient);
$scope.selectedIngredientResults = {};
var lengthofR = $scope.selectedIngredient.length;

for (var i = lengthofR - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var selected = $scope.selectedIngredient[i]['ingredient_id'];
    console.log('lengthofR', lengthofR);
    if(selected){
        if($scope.selectedIngredientResults.hasOwnProperty(selected)){

            $scope.selectedIngredientResults[$scope.selectedIngredient]++;
        }else {
      $scope.selectedIngredientResults[$scope.selectedIngredient] = 1;
        }
         console.log('$scope.selectedIngredientResults', $scope.selectedIngredientResults ); 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you identifying two objects as being the same (is it actually the same object, or just the same properties)?

Comment: please add some data for counting.

Comment: @ Paddy each object has ingredient_id and using obj.hasOwnProperty to identify for (var i = lengthofR - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     var selected = $scope.selectedIngredient[i]['ingredient_id'];
     console.log('lengthofR', lengthofR);
     if(selected){
      if($scope.selectedIngredientResults.hasOwnProperty(selected)){
       
       $scope.selectedIngredientResults[$scope.selectedIngredient]++;
      }else {
          $scope.selectedIngredientResults[$scope.selectedIngredient] = 1;
         }

Comment: I know it's not the answer, but for this kind of task lodash is great https://lodash.com/

Comment: If this is an AngularJS question, please tag it as so, as it may add different considerations than with vanilla Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to apply **group by** by your key. then extract the result from the grouping. here is a transform function what you would need.

```
function transform(items) {
    items = items.reduce(function (memo, val) {
        var key = val['ingredient_id'];
        if (!memo[key]) {
            memo[key] = [];
        }
        memo[key].push(val);

        return memo;
    }, {});

    var result = [];
    for (var k in items) {
        var groups = items[k];
        result.push({ 'object': groups[0], 'count': groups.length });
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: i am trying to understand your code, but  i still can not understand what's going on here  items = items.reduce(function (memo, val) {
        var key = val['ingredient_id'];
        if (!memo[key]) {
            memo[key] = [];
        }
        memo[key].push(val);

        return memo;
    }, {});

Comment: it's applying **group by** operation. just console.log(items) when reducing is done, you'll know what is been done for more abount **reduce** see(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). :)

Comment: can u explain val['ingredient_id'] ?@Sufian Saory

Comment: val is the current object for the reducing iteration. val['ingredient_id'] is the value of the ingredient_id which is the key for our group by operation. please see(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) with example of reduce.

Comment: Thanks @Sufian Saory

Answer (score 0):

```
function getIngredientResults (ingredients) {
  var source = [].slice.call(ingredients)
  var result = []

  while (source.length > 0) {
    // Move first item from source.
    var current = source.shift()

    // Find indexes of duplicate entries.
    var duplicateIndexes = source.reduce(function (carry, item, index) {
      if (item.ingredient_id === current.ingredient_id) {
        carry.push(index)
      }

      return carry
    }, [])

    // Remove duplicates from source.
    duplicateIndexes.forEach(function (index) {
      source.splice(index, 1)
    })

    // Add data to result
    result.push({
      ingredient: current,
      count: duplicateIndexes.length + 1
    })
  }

  return result
}
```

Comment: sorry @Jon Koops it is my fault, i should tag it AngularJS, but still thank your help

Comment: This is just a function, you can use it with AngularJS. AngularJS is still JavaScript...

Answer (score 0):

I guess this was already answered but here's how to do it in one reduce:

```
$scope.selectedIngredientResults = $scope.selectedIngredient.reduce(function (result, item) {
    var foundIndex = -1;
    var found = result.some(function (alreadyCounted, i) {
        if (alreadyCounted.object.ingredient_id === item.ingredient_id) {
            foundIndex = i;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    if (found && foundIndex !== -1) result[foundIndex].count += 1;
    else result.push({object: item, count: 1});
    return result;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

> **   I spend some time to learn these new methods above your guys answer and get some inspiration from these and worked it out by another way , Thank u so much guys **

```
myApp.controller('addIngredientCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.selectedIngredient = [];

$scope.addIngredient = function(selectedElement) {
var elementIndex = $scope.selectedIngredient.indexOf(selectedElement);
if(elementIndex === -1) {
  selectedElement['customerCartQuantity'] = 1;
  $scope.selectedIngredient.push(selectedElement);
} else {
  $scope.changeIngredientQuantity($scope.selectedIngredient[elementIndex],   1);
 }
 }

$scope.changeIngredientQuantity = function(selectedElement, value) {
var elementIndex = $scope.selectedIngredient.indexOf(selectedElement);
$scope.selectedIngredient[elementIndex].customerCartQuantity += value; 
if($scope.selectedIngredient[elementIndex].customerCartQuantity == 0) {
  $scope.selectedIngredient.splice(elementIndex, 1);
}
```

}
});